# Unique identifier per device, over multiple apps

Tags: ios, swift, fingerprint, devicecheck

Apple recently brought up their new DeviceCheck API which allows the developer to uniquely identify a device from the same developer / team ID. I am looking for a way to have same functionality but through all apps. Meaning App independent. The advertising ID would be sufficient, but because of several reasons I can not use it. Does somebody have additional ideas?

Comment: DeviceCheck doesn't exactly uniquely identify a device. It lets you associate two bits with a device. `identifierForVendor` gives you an identifier across all apps from the same developer on a device but this identifier changes if the device is erased.

Comment: Yeah, but identifierForVendor also is different across apps from different developers... I need an identifier across different apps from different devs...

Comment: There is no such thing, by design, for privacy reasons